# Can Karate Stand a Chance Against Aikido

Tags: tae-kwon-do, karate, aikido, sparring

I'm not an expert in martial arts but I always wanted to know if a offensive-based martial art, like Karate and Taekwondo, is capable of lasting or even defeating a fighter that uses Aikido.  I've seen a few YouTube videos of Aikido in action and, so far, I've noticed the Aikido practitioner barely takes any hits from a fighter who used Taekwondo.  In fact, almost every attempt the Taekwondo fighter made ends up with him being in a joint lock or on the ground.  Like I said, I'm not an expert so I probably don't know the whole story on either fighting style.  So can any of you help me answer this question?

Comment: Comparison of martial arts styles is out of scope. Too many variables, devolves to gorilla Vs shark.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  gorilla Vs shark.

Comment: Since you're not a martial artist, I'll start with some terminology. The suffixes "do" and "jutsu" are used almost interchangably when describing martial arts of japanese origin. More formally, "do" is the sport or self improvement form,  "jutsu" is the survival form.  Most serious martial artists study at least one striking form, one grappling form, and one weapons form.  Most systems incorporate elements of other systems, so karate has a strong aiki component, and aiki practitioners do practice strikes. The last six(ish) movements of Pinan 1 (1st karate kata) are a basic aikido exercise.

Comment: It's almost always dependent on the skill/training level of the practitioner, more than the martial art itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as an offensive-based martial art.  Only the fighter can do or be offensive things.

Karate is inanimate, and so it cannot stand, let alone stand a chance.  Only the fighter can be better than another, and then only for an instance.

YouTube does not bestow wisdom, intelligence, capability, nor knowledge.  It can only report what had happened at the time the video was made.  The same video can be shown in different contexts and tell very different stories.  Best to stay away from YouTube until you have a better understanding of martial arts in general.

But as to specifics about what you saw, the Aikido-ka didn't get hit because he employed the first rule of self-defense: "don't be there", sometimes stated as "get outta the way!".  This mantra exists in all styles, whether it is for self-defense or for sport.

Don't worry about what you see on YouTube.  It is no guarantee about what you will experience, or what you will be, or what you can do, or what can happen to you.  YouTube shouldn't even be part of your resources until you are well under way in your training, and then only judiciously used.  Therein creates many misconceptions and myths, which we martial arts - of all styles - work hard to dispell.

Comment: Oh, so basically anything could happen in that case?  I guess it was a little silly of me to judge by what I saw on the YouTube videos. ^^;

Comment: Yes, anything can happen - including luck can have a factor.  But no, I wouldn't say "silly".  Many people ask, even those already in martial arts.  And YouTube videos have a dubious use.  They can be helpful, and they can be used to misinform.  I haven't seen your video, so I can't really comment on it, and only make a generalization.

Comment: The obvious thing is that when you see youtube videos showing superiority of one fighting style over the other, it's usually a canned demonstration. In other words, it's not a real fight. One of the two is being compliant and letting the other guy do stuff. It might even be spontaneous, but punches and kicks are coming slowly and from a mile a way, and once the aikido guy gets a hold of the karate guy's wrist, for example, the karate guy doesn't try to yank it back or kick the aikido guy in the legs. He just lets the aikido guy do stuff. That's fakery. Don't believe any of it.

Comment: @Micheal - If you want a somewhat recent example of a great striker defeating a great grappler (an olympic judoka, even), just watch Holly Holm vs Ronda Rousey again. Each style has its strengths and weaknesses, but it's up to the fighters involved to capitalize on them.